# htaccess specific URL rewriting to new domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to redirect olddomain.com to newdomain.com but I want the old URL to point to the correct new pages. The old URL is: /index.cfm?fuseaction=browse&id=50706&pageid=40, and the new url is /all-products/

I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.cfm?fuseaction=browse&id=50706&pageid=40 http://newdomain.com/all-products/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

and

```
Rewrite 301 index.cfm?fuseaction=browse&id=50706&pageid=40 http://newdomain.com/all-products/
```

With various tweaks in the .htaccess file of olddomain.com, but I get nothing but 404 errors. Creating a test link: `RewriteRule ^test http://newdomain.com/all-products/ [R=301,NC,L]` DOES redirect correctly. Is there a character I need to escape in the old URL? I'm not sure if this is relevant but FollowSymLinks is disabled by my host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RewriteRule` doesn't match `QUERY_STRING`. You need to use `RewriteCond`.

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^fuseaction=browse&id=50706&pageid=40(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.cfm$ http://newdomain.com/all-products/? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: Brilliant! Is there a simple way to get the final url to be /all-products/ instead of /all-products/?fuseaction=browse&id=50706&pageid=40 ? My edits so far just break your example.

Comment: Because of trailing `?` in the target URI, final URL will be without query string i.e. `http://newdomain.com/all-products/` Make sure to use a a different browser to test it because of 301 caching issues.